# Gmail Contextual Gadget not Showing up with the new Apps Marketplace Publishing guidelines

Tags: gmail, google-apps-marketplace, gmail-contextual-gadgets

When I try to deploy the gadget from Google Apps console, it works perfectly on my own domain. However, when I publish now using the COB extension through Google Apps API console, following all the steps listed here: developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/preparing, it gets installed on other domains, but the gadget itself never shows up. I waited for 2 days and also used the no-cache option with no avail.

Would really appreciate someone's help and support!

Comment: I'm having the same issue, and would really appreciate an answer from Google, or at least a set of debugging steps to check for some obvious errors

Comment: @LcLk Google Remove the Total manifest file. you have to just write the information on the google application console just remove some scope on your json file